# Changing variable type at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class hierarchy (In .Net 3.5) as shown:

```
Parent
   - Child1
   - Child2
   - Child3
```

I have a base class as shown:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected Parent field;

    public BaseClass(Parent someField)
    {
        this.field = someField
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return field.Child1Property; }
        set { field.Child1Property = value; }
    }
}
```

The parameter that I'm passing in the constructor is going to be one of the Children. Is there a way to access the Child properties through a variable of the Parent type?

Alternately, is it possible to do this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected Parent field;
    protected Type childType; //Type? Or something else?

    public BaseClass(Parent someField)
    {
        //assign the runtime type of someField to childType
        this.field = someField
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return ((childType)field).Child1Property; }  //Is this possible?
        set { ((childType)field).Child1Property = value; }
    }
}
```

If I use Type it doesn't seem to work since  ((childType)field).Child1Property is not allowed. The problem is, I only find out what type of child is being passed at runtime so casting the field to the appropriate type doesn't seem to be possible.

Help!

Comment: like a __dynamic__ object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected Parent field;

    public BaseClass(Parent someField)
    {
        this.field = someField
        if (someField is Child1)
            this.Property1 = ((Child1)someField).Foo();
    }

    public Int32 Property1
    {
        get { return field.Child1Property; }
        set { field.Child1Property = value; }
    }
}
```

***However***, there is a caveat here.  You need to *know* that the instance of `parent` being passed in is of type `Child1`, or nothing will happen.  Generally it's considered a bad design to have an if/then that covers every possible child class, because that means that when you add another child in the future, you'll need to remember to come back here and add it to the if/then.

The proper way to do this is really to have a property in Parent that is overriden in child:

```
public class Parent {
    public virtual Int32 Foo() { return 5; }
}

public class Child1 : Parent {
    public override Int32 Foo() { return 7; } 
}
```

And then use that property:

```
    public BaseClass(Parent someField)
    {
        this.field = someField

        // If someField happens to be a Child1, this will be 7
        this.Property1 = someField.Foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you propably want to use an [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).